# Convert one dimensional array into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

suppose i have this array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [name] => ELECTRONICS
    [depth] => 0
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [name] => TELEVISIONS
    [depth] => 1
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [name] => TUBE
    [depth] => 2
  )

  [3] => Array
  (
    [name] => LCD
    [depth] => 2
  )

  [4] => Array
  (
    [name] => PLASMA
    [depth] => 2
  )

  [5] => Array
  (
    [name] => PORTABLE ELECTRONICS
    [depth] => 1
  )
)
```

i want it to be converted into a multi-dimensional array such that immediate elements with a depth higher than the previous element will go inside the previous element with the key "children". like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [name] => ELECTRONICS
    [depth] => 0
    [children] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [name] => TELEVISIONS
        [depth] => 1
        [children] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
          (
            [name] => TUBE
            [depth] => 2
          )

          [1] => Array
          (
            [name] => LCD
            [depth] => 2
          )

          [2] => Array
          (
            [name] => PLASMA
            [depth] => 2
          )
        )
      )

      [1] => Array
      (
        [name] => PORTABLE ELECTRONICS
        [depth] => 1
      )
    )
  )
)
```

would greatly appreciate your help. thanks ;)

Comment: I am currently at my wits end trying to come-up with some array_push approach using a couple of if conditions in a for loop but sadly to no avail...

Comment: There's no logical connection in the code here between parent and child.  The only thing you know with your initial input is depth levels.  One could potentially create a tree based solely on depth, but it looks like you're nesting like terms.  TUBE, LCD and PLASMA are child to TELEVISIONS but PORTABLE ELECTRONICS has no children.  How does the code know the relationship?

Comment: oops, sorry i missed this: "i want it to be converted into a multi-dimensional array such that immediate elements with a depth higher than the previous element will go inside the previous element with the key "children""

Comment: use one integer var to remember your current level, and an array to keep a reference to the last element of each level. That way when you go back one level up you will know where to continue inserting

Comment: almost have a solution, just working out one last bug. this is a though one. :)

Comment: great puzzle!  I think "dancing links" is the applicable algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my crack at it... Uses a foreach loop and an array of pointers to keep track of a bunch of different parent pointers.

```
$multi_dimensional = array();
$last_depth = 0;
$parent = &$multi_dimensional;
$parents[$last_depth] = &$parent;


foreach ($start as $idx => $data) {
  // same/increasing depth
  if ($last_depth <= $data['depth']) {
    $parent['children'][] = $data;  
  } 

  // increasing depth
  if ($last_depth < $data['depth']) {
    $parents[$last_depth] = &$parent;
  }

  // decreasing depth
  if ($last_depth > $data['depth']) {
    $parent = &$parents[$data['depth']-1];
    $parent['children'][] = $data;  
  }

  // look ahead and prepare parent in increasing
  if (isset($start[$idx+1]) && $start[$idx+1]['depth'] > $data['depth']) {
    $last_insert_idx = count($parent['children'])-1;
    $parent = &$parent['children'][$last_insert_idx];
  }
  $last_depth = $data['depth'];
}

// initial values are in child "children" array
$result = $multi_dimensional['children'];
```

Comment: cernunnos' recursive solution also works but this one is more efficient since it's non-recursive. thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

That was a tricky one. I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way of achieving this, but it works:

```
function flat_to_tree($array, $depth = 0)
{
  $out = array();
  $inCurrentDepth = true;

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['depth'] < $depth) {
      return $out;
    }

    if ($value['depth'] === $depth) {
      $inCurrentDepth = true;
      $out[] = $value;
    }

    if ($inCurrentDepth && $value['depth'] > $depth) {
      $inCurrentDepth = false;
      $out[$key - 1]['children'] = flat_to_tree(array_slice($array, $key), $value['depth']);
    }
  }

  return $out;
}
```

Comment: nice use of recursion and php-native functions.  i went the less exciting foreach loop approach

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the name and the recursive nature of it. Also, notice that this function will "destroy" your original array so use a clone if you want to keep it

```
function multiDimensionate(&$arr, $currentLevel = 0) {
  $root = array();

  foreach ($arr as &$elem){
    if ($elem["depth"] == $currentLevel) {
      $root[] = $elem;
      unset($elem);
    } else if ($elem["depth"] == $currentLevel + 1) {
      $root[count($root)-1]["children"] = multiDimensionate($arr,$elem["depth"]);      
    }
  }

  return $root;
}
```

Edit: As pointed out in the coments the previous function wasnt working properly, this should be ok, still has the side effect of destroying the original array.

Comment: looks like PORTABLE ELECTRONICS doesn't get boosted back up to the top level